# TweetSharp. How to withdraw ListFollower in listbox?

Tags: c#, listbox

Using TweetSharp I am counting the list of followers. How can I withdraw it to the ListBox?

Here is the code:

```
var options = new ListFollowersOptions { ScreenName = "tanya_000120" };
var ids = ts.ListFollowers(options); //there is an exception here

foreach (var id in ids) 
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(id.ScreenName);
}
```

Comment: What exception? Make sure ts != null.

Comment: @romanoza ts is okey. exception: System.InvalidCastException

Comment: What is the StackTrace for this exception?